# Backbone.js DELETE request not firing

Tags: backbone.js, synchronization

I'm trying to get the backbone.js DELETE request to fire, but don't see any requests being made in my console.

I have collection model like so:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend(
{
    urlRoot: '/test',
    defaults:{}
});

var TableList = Backbone.Collection.extend(
{
    url: '/test',
    model: Model
});
```

In my view I'm running this:

```
this.model.destroy();
```

Everything seems to be running fine, I can see output coming from the remove function that calls the destroy so I know it's getting there plus it also successfully runs an unrender method that I have.  Can't see any requests being made to the sever though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue to my problem, thought not a solution yet.  I'm not sure this is a bug with backbone or not, but I'm using `ajaxSetup` and `ajaxPrefilter`.  I tried commenting it out and it worked.  I narrowed it down to the ajaxSetup method and the specifically the use of the `data` parameter to preset some values.

Comment: If someone has the "no delete request" problem only in Firefox but not in Chrome, then it's likely that this is exactly your problem. After removing `data : { }` from `ajaxSetup` everything was fine. Thanks, you made my day.

Answer (score 14):

If I am not mistaken, you have to have an id property on your model to ensure that it hits the correct url. IE if your model was...

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/some/url'
});

var model = new Model({
    id: 1 
});
model.destroy(); // I THINK it will now try and DELETE to /some/url/1
```

Without an id it doesn't know how to build the url correctly, typically you'd fetch the model, or create a new one and save it, then you'd have a Url...

See if that helps!

Comment: Yep, the id is set, I can see it in the if I output this.model.

Comment: I have both url and urlRoot set, but still nothing.  I should be seeing a request made in firebug right, or am I totally missing something?

Comment: Yea, you probably should be... I'll look at it a little deeper... Do you have a Fiddle anywhere?

Comment: I added the `new Model({id: 1}).destroy();` line and that triggers the request fine, but doesn't seem to be triggering within my view.

Comment: thanks for this answer.  I put `idAttribute: "_id"` in the model and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using success and error callbacks?

```
this.model.destroy({
    success : _.bind(function(model, response) {
                  ...some code
              }, this),
    error : _.bind(function(model, response) {
                  ...some code
              }, this);
});
```

Might be instructive if you're not seeing a DELETE request.

Comment: This triggers the success callback for me, but still no request to the server.  It's very strange, I thought it was supposed to just work out of the box, it's like I'm missing some kind of hook up for this.

Comment: Looks like you're doing things correctly. If you refresh your page, do the changes stick? Also, have you stepped through to ensure that the code is actually getting to the jquery ajax call? This is a bit weird because I haven't seen this behavior at all myself.

Comment: So after some playing with callbacks, I'm seeing something in the error callback response.statusText - "[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA)" nsresult: "0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA)" location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 4" data: no]" - so apparently the url is not being formed properly, is there anyway to view the url it's trying to use?

Comment: You SHOULD be able to see it in Firebug or Chrome dev tools, but if not, debug it at this line in Backbone.sync towards the bottom `return $.ajax(_.extend(params, options));`

Comment: Okay, so I output the params to the console which gives me : `{"type":"DELETE","dataType":"json","url":"/test/94","processData":false}`, which all seems good to me, at this point it's just running the jQuery $.ajax request.

Comment: I'm using jQuery's `ajaxPrefilter` and even that's being called as well, I completely commented out to see if it was an issue, but still no request.

Comment: But ajaxPrefilter shouldn't have an effect unless there's a default option that says: Do the request but don't output it...