# Backbone model.remove not sending DELETE

Tags: mongodb, backbone.js, mongoose

I have a collection of bookmarks (books for short in my code) and when I call call @books.remove(book), a DELETE request is never sent. I can see my collection updates - the model is gone, but the request is not sent. POST and GET work fine.

I'm using Node, MongoDB and Mongoose.

I have a sense it has something to do with the id(s) I'm using - that's confusing me a bit for sure.

I have the mongoose id: "_id" and then an ID that references the movie ID for the rotten tomatoes API: "rottenID"

---

Here is an example of my JSON GET response:

```
[{"_id":"5484961502c054fb59dea18a","rottenId":771364788,"__v":0}]
```

---

Here is my model:

```
class Bookmark extends Backbone.Model
    idAttribute: "_id"
    url: "/api/movies/bookmarks
```

---

Here is my collection:

```
class BookmarksCollection extends Movies
     model: Bookmark
```

---

Removing a book in my view:

```
book = @books.where({rottenId: id})
@books.remove(book)
```

---

Here is what things look like in the console:

[image: IMG]

---

I've read about other people having this problem for example in the following posts, but I can't seem to get their solutions to work for me:

[Backbone.js DELETE request not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744579/backbone-js-delete-request-not-firing)

[RESTful Express Mongoose & Backbone - Backbone model.remove() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881787/restful-express-mongoose-backbone-backbone-model-remove-not-working)

[backbone model.destroy not triggering a DELETE request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037226/backbone-model-destroy-not-triggering-a-delete-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
book = @books.findWhere({rottenId: id})
@books.remove(book)
```

does exactly what it says, it removes `book` from `@books`. However, removing a model from the collection has nothing to do with removing the model from the server. If you want to delete the `book` instance, you need to do

```
book = @books.findWhere({rottenId: id})
book.destroy();
```

which also has the side-effect of removing the model from the collection automatically.

Comment: Thanks loganfsmyth - I tried this but am getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" - any idea what's going wrong here? I can log out the book var and it shows an object exists?

Comment: I realized I was getting the undefined error because my @books.where({rottenId: id}) was giving me an object that contained the model...not the model itself, so when I did "book = (@books.where({rottenId: id}))[0]" I was able to get the model itself. I'm guessing if I need to do this though I'm doing something else wrong as well?

Comment: Oh right, you need to do `.findWhere` to get a single instance.